# probability related to function mapping

Tags: probability

> **let $F$ denotes the set of all onto functions from $A=\{ a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4 \}$ to $B=\{ x,y,z \}$. A function $f(x)$ is chosen at random from set $F$ such that
> $f^{-1}(x)$ contains only one element**

so I started by finding the number of elements in set $F$,
which is $81-48+3=36$ (by principle of inclusion-exclusion)

now since the inverse of $f(x)$ is defined only at one value what I can do is select one element from set $A$ and another element from set $B$ and pair them up permanently
so the number ways is $4*3$

so all I have to do now is to pair 3 elements from set $A$ to 2 elements from set $B$ such that every element in set $B$ has at least one pair which again by principle of inclusion-exclusion is given by $2^3-2=6$

but the total possibilities

$(3*4*6=72)$

exceed the sample space

what have I done wrong ????

Comment: Your question is flawed as there exists *no* $f^{-1}(x)$. Since $A$ has 4 elements and $B$ has 3, there is no function $f:A\to B$ which is injective.

Comment: Do you mean all functions that map all 4 elements in A to a single element in B? As @Cathedral notes, your current question doesn't appear to make sense.

Comment: if a1 is mapped to x and a2 to y,a3 to y and a4 to z then wouldn't f^-1(x) b such that x belongs to belongs to {a1}  be invertible?

Comment: @Cathedral have i got something  wrong?

Comment: If `f(a1) = f(a2) = x`, then what is `f^-1(x)`?

Comment: @MeetLalwani In the example you give, what would be $f^{-1}(y)$? There also appears to be some confusion between the $x$ in $f(x)$ and the $x$ belonging to the set $B$... consider editing the elements to $b_1, b_2$ and $b_3$

Comment: @MeetLalwani $\sin (x)$ most definitely is *not* one-one in $[0, \pi ]$

Comment: sin(x) is invertible from -pi/2 to +pi/2 for example, but not 0 to pi

Comment: @barrycarter wht i mean is if we change to domain such that the function becomes invertible how many such function can be found?

Comment: If you map a 4-element set into a 3-element set, you must map two elements to a single element by the pigeonhole principle. Feel free to chat me if you want to discuss in more detail, because I'm not sure I'm following your question. Alternately, provide examples of three functions f that meet your criteria by editing your original question